# Renaming multiple files based on their contents

Tags: rename

How can I rename all files within a folder with the first word of their content? For example if a.txt contains “Unix is an OS” in its first line then a.txt should be renamed to Unix.txt

Comment: Please correct title into something like "How do I rename multiple file in unix?"

Comment: Missed that on this site, I thought I did not have enought rep here...

Comment: That title is also too misleading.  It leaves out the core detail that the new name must be based on file *content*.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
for f in *.txt; do d="$(head -1 "$f" | awk '{print $1}').txt"; if [ ! -f "$d" ]; then mv "$f" "$d"; else echo "File '$d' already exists! Skiped '$f'"; fi; done
```

or more long variant (as script):

```
#!/bin/sh
for f in *.txt; do
    d="$(head -1 "$f" | awk '{print $1}').txt"
    if [ ! -f "$d" ]; then
        mv "$f" "$d"
    else
        echo "File '$d' already exists! Skiped '$f'"
    fi
done
```

In case when destination file exists this one-liner skips it.

Comment: I'd simplify `head -1 "$f" | awk '{print $1}'` to `<"$f" awk {print $1; exit}`.

Comment: This doesn't work if the first line has spaces in it...

Answer (score 4):

Here is my *approach*.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *; 
do
    if [[ -f $file ]]; 
    then
        # cut word by single white space
        fileword=$(head -n1 "$file" | cut -f1 -d" ");
        # Everything after first dot is considered as extention
        ext=$(echo $file | sed 's/.*\.\(.*\)/.\1/g')
        [ "$file" != "$fileword" ] && $(mv  "$file"  "$fileword$ext")
    fi;
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this *oneliner*

```
for i in *; do if [ ! -f $i ]; then echo "skipping $i"; else newname=`head -1 $i | sed 's/^\s*\([a-zA-Z0-9]\+\).*$/\1/'`; [ -n "$newname" ] && mv -i $i $newname.txt || echo "error at: $i"; fi; done
```

This will replace all files with the first word in that file + `.txt`. I defined *first word* to be the first occurrence of `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`, discarding leading white spaces.
**Disclaimer:** Please just use it if you are sure that there is a *first word* on line one in each file! Otherwise you might experience unexpected results ;-)

Comment: Gah! [Don't parse the output of ls!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) The shell already knows how to act on all the files in a directory, it's spelled `*`.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
for i in *.txt
do
d="$(head -1 "$i" | cut -d " " -f1).txt";
mv "$i" "$d"
done
```

Comment: The character after the first word could be different than space (a comma for example)

Answer (score -1):

```sh
for i in *.txt; do mv "$i" "$(head -1 "$i")".txt; done
```

Comment: First *word*, not first *line*.

Answer (score -2):

On your own risk: :)

```
find -exec echo -n mv {} " " ";" -exec sed '1s/ .*//;q' {} ";" > tmp.sh && bash tmp.sh
```

This works with easy filenames, containing easy words. A file "O'Reilly" containing as first word "Eto'o" will fail. Miserably.

Comment: You're missing a step of quoting. What if there's a file called `some'thing`, or if the first word is `D'oh`?

Comment: Yes, I see. How would you do it? Not at all - choose a different approach?

Comment: It's technically possible to generate a shell script, but it's calling for trouble. You “just” need to get the quoting right. There's no call for it here, just extract the first word and call `mv` right there, like the other answers. You can keep your sed command, it's a fine way to extract the first word.

Comment: In praxis, I would, if I used this approach, use two commands - `... > tmp.sh`, and review tmp.sh manually. Then invoke `bash tmp.sh`. With a lot of funky filenames, I wouldn't do it at all. But one or two manual corrections would be fine in 100 files. In about 1000 files, a manual review would start becoming work.