# ranaming multiple file in unix

Tags: rename

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Renaming multiple files in unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13157/renaming-multiple-files-in-unix)

Rename all files within a folder with the first word of their content(remember all the files should be text files. For example if a.txt contains “Unix is an OS” in its first line then a.txt should be renamed to Unix.txt