# Create small record files from a big group of record file

Tags: awk, large-files

I have a file like this :

Mainfile:

```
Record|1111|ABC     
text in between for record 1     
text in between for record 1     
Record|2222|XYZ     
text in between for record 2     
Record|3333|XYZ     
text in between for record 3
```

I want to create smaller files which contains each record data

File : **1111**

```
Record|1111|ABC    
text in between for record 1    
text in between for record 1
```

File : **2222**

```
Record|2222|XYZ
text in between for record 2
```

File : **3333**

```
Record|3333|XYZ
text in between for record 3
```

Currently I am using awk to do this :

```
awk -F"|" '
/Record/{ 
        if(s>0) {
             print line > r;
         }
s=1; 
r=$2; 
line=$0 
} 
!/Record/
{ 
line=line"\n"$0; 
}

END
{
    print line > r;
}' file
```

But it is taking more time to process the file. Each file is 4GB in size and will contain around 75k+ Records.

Is there any faster way to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk, you can try:

```
gawk -v RS='Record[|]' -F'|' '$1{printf "%s%s", RT, $0 > $1}' file
```

With `Record|` as the [record separator](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Records.html), we can easily obtain each record. GNU awk's `RS` can be a regular expression (as in this case), and `RT` contains the text which matched this expression (`Record|`).

With `mawk`, `RT` isn't available, so you can use `printf "Record|%s", $0` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Now if the need to base output file names on file content can be removed, coreutils [csplit](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/csplit-invocation.html) may be faster at this than `awk`

```
csplit file '/^Record[|]/' '{*}'
```

This will create a set of files `xx01`, `xx02` and so on. You can ignore the `xx01` file since in your case it is going to be empty. Also note that `csplit` lets you configure the prefix (`xx`) and suffix (`01`, `02`....) parts of output file names

Comment: +1, One can always rename the files after `csplit` is done.

Comment: @muru : how to do that renaming part ?

Comment: @SinoopJoy something like: `for i in xx*; do mv $i $(awk -F'|' '{print $1; exit}'); done` - See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13157/renaming-multiple-files-based-on-their-contents